# How does Spark DataFrame handles Pandas DataFrame that is larger than memory

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, hdf5

I am learning Spark now, and it seems to be the big data solution for Pandas Dataframe, but I have this question which makes me unsure.

Currently I am storing Pandas dataframes that are larger than memory using HDF5. HDF5 is a great tool which allows me to do chunking on the pandas dataframe. So when I need to do processing on large Pandas dataframe, I will do it in chunks. But Pandas does not support distributed processing and HDF5 is only for a single PC environment.

Using Spark dataframe may be solution, but my understanding of Spark is the dataframe must be able to fit in memory, and once loaded as a Spark dataframe, Spark will distribute the dataframe to the different workers to do the distributed processing.

Is my understanding correct? If this is the case, then how does Spark handle a dataframe that is larger than the memory? Does it support chunking, like HDF5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the dataframe must be able to fit in memory, and once loaded as a Spark dataframe, Spark will distribute the dataframe to the different workers to do the distributed processing.

This is true only if you're trying to load your data on a driver and then parallelize. In a typical scenario you store data in a format which can be read in parallel. It means your data:

- has to be accessible on each worker, for example using distributed file system
- file format has to support splitting (the simplest examples is plain old csv)

In situation like this each worker reads only its own part of the dataset without any need to store data in a driver memory. All logic related to computing splits is handled transparently by the applicable Hadoop Input Format.

Regarding HDF5 files you have two options:

- read data in chunks on a driver, build Spark DataFrame from each chunk, and union results. This is inefficient but easy to implement
- distribute HDF5 file / files and read data directly on workers. This generally speaking harder to implement and requires a smart data distribution strategy

Comment: Assuming that I have a large dataframe that cannot be fit into memory, in parquet format on disk. And I am running spark locally. How does spark load this dataframe in partitions? Does it partition the dataframe automatically and do the processing (e.g. counting value occurrences for each column of the dataframe), or do I have to manually partition this dataframe into chunks and store them in parquet, and then call spark, tell it where are the chunks stored, and do the processing?

Comment: Regarding the first question it is handled internally usually using an applicable Hadoop Input Format. I am not sure if I understand the second question though.  If data is already stored in a Parquet then there is nothing else to do beyond making sure it actually fits in a memory. If you want to convert HDF5 to parquet then you have to manually partition.

Comment: Let me reframe the second question, as I have been reading up on the spark documentation. Let us assume that we have a cluster, and I have a raw data that can't be fit in the memory of any node. Does the following pipeline to load and process the file makes sense to you? raw data in csv -> parallelize raw data to rdd at driver -> convert rdd to spark dataframe at driver -> do the necessary data processing -> store the spark dataframe to parquet. For the last step, the data is still larger than memory, but its partitions are stored in different nodes, as determined by spark.

Comment: No, it doesn't If you have splittable just make sure it is accessible on all of the workers (in local mode there is nothing to do, on the cluster it means either DFS or local copy) and read it using [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) (or `SparkContext.textFile`, but I wouldn't recommend that).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The main reason for loading the raw data at driver is to allow spark to parallelize the data to rdd, using spark's standalone cluster manager, with the assumption that the cluster can support the rdd without memory crash. Are you suggesting the following pipeline: raw data in csv -> use spark-csv to load raw data to spark dataframe at driver -> do the necessary data processing -> store the spark dataframe to parquet.

Comment: With one important difference. Data loading happens on the workers. In local it can be the same physical machine but there is still a difference.

Comment: Ok, I think I get your point. If my raw data is stored in a DFS, I can set this raw data to be accessible to both Spark driver and workers. So when my driver do a parallelize or spark-csv on raw data, it will not have out of memory problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93866/discussion-between-zero323-and-michael).