# How to tell if spark session will be able to hold data size in dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark

Intend to read data from an Oracle DB with pyspark (running in local mode) and store locally as parquet. Is there a way to tell whether a spark session dataframe will be able to hold the amount of data from the query (which will be the whole table, ie. `select * from mytable`)? Are there common solutions for if the data would not be able to fit in a dataframe?

* Saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33420229/8236733), but was a little confused by the discussion in the comments

Comment: Just some more info: https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-spark-101-3f961c89b8c5#7d02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running on local, So I assume it is not on a cluster. You can not say exactly how much memory would require? However, you can go close to it. You check your respective table size that how much disk space it's using. Suppose you `mytable` has occupied `1GB` of Hard disk then spark would be required RAM more than that, because Spark's engine required some memory for its own processing. Try to have `2GB` extra, for safer side than actual table size.

To check you table size in Oracle, You can use below query:

```
select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB
 from dba_segments
 where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='<yourtablename>';
```

It will give you a result in `MB`.

To configure JVM related parameter in `Apache-Spark` you can check [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how big the table is if you are running spark in a distributed manner. You would need to worry about the memory if:-

1. You are reading the data in the driver and then doing a broadcast.
2. Caching the dataframe for some computation.

Usually for your spark application a DAG gets generated and if you are using JDBC source then the workers will read the data directly and use the shuffle space and off-heap to disk for memory intensive computation.

Comment: "*Usually for your spark application a DAG gets generated and if you are using JDBC source then the workers will read the data directly and use the shuffle space and off-heap to disk for memory intensive computation.*" Have been interested in how this works. Could you comment a link to some docs that explain this a bit more?

Comment: You can take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html for more details, it is very similar to how Sqoop works.Another good link can be found here - https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/17/apache-spark-makes-slow-mysql-queries-10x-faster/